# Does iPhone/iOS development allow the use of third-party compiled libraries?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

We're currently negotiating an outsourced iPhone development - and one of our requirements is that we also get the project source at the end of the development to allow us to enhance/update once the initial app is released.

The developer does not want to release the source of their own common libraries - which is understandable - and have said that they will have to write new code to replace those libraries.

However - on other platforms, it is possible to include libraries as pre-compiled software so that the source code is not necessarily released. Is this possible with iPhone app development? And if so, is it easy to implement?

Comment: I know this is possible, but I don't know enough to tell you how. Libraries like OCMock are compiled into static .a libs and included as frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly possible look at the admob or flurry libraries for example

To make a static library look here http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html